# How a new node trusts another node in the network

Tags: stellar-core, scp

Let's assume that a new node joined in the network.As per the SCP how this new node trusts another node in the network?

Does this happens by exchanging messages between other nodes in the network ? If yes on what basis it starts trusting the other node or nodes.

Answer (score 4):

This certainly deserves a more complete answer than I'm about to give, and hopefully someone can go ahead and give it -- but the root of it is that a node chooses (manually) which other notes to include in its quorum slices.

Check out this nice article on the SCP and how quorum slices function: https://etale-cohomology.github.io/stellar-tutorials/blog1.html

A new node can join the network and it can load the history and perform validation -- but if no one includes it in its quorum slices then its decisions won't affect the rest of the networks.